# Cannot read property instance of undefined Angular 8

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ngx-image-cropper

I have a modal, in which one I would use a component (ngx-image-cropper) but I get this error everytime "Cannot read property instance of undefined" on the image-cropper.

Preview() is called successfully and this.logoToUpload works fine, the problem is to open the modal with the image-cropper component, otherwise also the modal works fine.

Here is my code:

```
import { ImageCroppedEvent, LoadedImage } from 'ngx-image-cropper';

@Component({
  selector: 'logo',
  templateUrl: './logo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./logo.component.scss']
})
export class LogoComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(
    private modalService: NgbModal,
  ) {}

ngOnInit() {}

preview(content) {
    var mimeType = this.logoToUpload.type;
    if (mimeType.match(/image\/*/) == null) {
      return;
    }
    debugger;
    // Show preview
    this.modalService.open(content).result.then(
      (result) => {
        //DO SOMETHING IN CASE RESULT IS SAVE OR NOT
      }, (reason) => {
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
<ng-template #modalCroppingImage let-modal>
  <div class="modal-header modal-header-new">
    Select area
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
   <image-cropper [imageFile]="logoToUpload"
                   [maintainAspectRatio]="true"
                   [aspectRatio]="4 / 3"
                   format="png"
                   (imageCropped)="imageCropped($event)"
                   (imageLoaded)="imageLoaded()"
                   (cropperReady)="cropperReady()"
                   (loadImageFailed)="loadImageFailed()"></image-cropper>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary button-modal-detail-new" (click)="modal.close('Save'); resetView();">SAVE<!--Close--></button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary button-modal-detail-new" (click)="modal.close('Close'); resetView();">CLOSE<!--Close--></button>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

Edit: I also get this error:

StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[ImageCropperComponent -> CropService]:
StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[ImageCropperComponent -> CropService]:
NullInjectorError: No provider for CropService!

Comment: Try `public modalService`? Just a guess. Also, in your view, `modal` is undefined (there is no `this.modal` in your component), I guess it should be `(click)="modalService.close('Save')"`

Comment: There's `let-modal` on the template. It's a `ng-bootstrap` modal: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples#basic

Comment: What's the stacktrace for the error? You should check it.

Comment: @Totati What do you mean with let-modal is the problem?

Comment: I saw I also get this error in console:  StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[ImageCropperComponent -> CropService]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[ImageCropperComponent -> CropService]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for CropService!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, ngx-image-cropper is no more supported on Angular 8. If you have the same problem, you have to install the 3.3.5 version.